# Regex match the space bewtween matches as well?

Tags: regex

I'm not new to regex (or SO), but I can't seem to find a solid solution for matching the leftover spaces between matches.

For instance, I want to know what is inside quotes, and what is not, and do things to both.

Getting quotes is easy:  `(\".+?\"|'.+?') = quoteMatch`

but making another match group to select everything else is not.

The closest I've gotten is `quoteMatch+'|(.)'`.  This will separate my quote groups from my everything else groups, but it doesn't group together the 'else groups.

Trying `quoteMatch+'|(.+)'` selects everything together and `quoteMatch+'|(.+?)'` puts me back a step.

I imagine I need to find a way to make the first match more greedy than the second, but anything I do to make it greedy makes it start taking over multiple quotes and the things in between (ie. match = `"quote1" things in between "quote2"`.

I've also looked into using the split function, but it doesn't return what the split was, and is not quite as eloquent of a solution as I imagine must exist.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the match for selecting the other character to the inside of the capturing group as an alternation:

```
(\".+?\"|'.+?'|.+?(?=["']|$))
```

Then you can use a positive lookahead such as `(?=["']|$)` in order to match until a quote or the end of the line.

[**Live Example**](https://regex101.com/r/tR9gL4/1)

In doing so, an input of:

> before quotes "quote1" in between quotes "quote2" after quotes

Would return:

```
(before quotes ), ("quote1"), ( in between quotes ), ("quote2"), ( after quotes)
```

---

As a side note, you can also combine the first two alternations by using a backreference to close the quote:

```
((['"]).+?\2|.+?(?=["']|$))
```

Comment: Yes.  Thank you.  This took me a minute to figure out, but now I get it, it's super rad.  I get the feeling things would be a lot less pretty if I wasn't just looking for quotes, and perhaps the tiny amount of repetition `?=['"]` can be avoided, but thank you!